# hibernate annotations schema generation many-to-many OnDelete cascade

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have a ManyToMany relation defined with hibernate annotations and I create my schema with hbm2ddl, the join table is created with the foreign keys, but I didn't manage to add the 'on delete cascade' action to the foreign keys.
I tried with:
@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
but I get this exception:

only inverse one-to-many associations may use on-delete="cascade"

If I manually add on delete cascade to my schema it works fine.

I am using hibernate 3.5.3 with JPA 2.0 and postgres 8.4

Is it possible to add 'on delete cascade' to join tables foreign keys create with hbm2ddl ?

## Update

```
ClassA
{
    @OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = ClassB.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "CLASS_A_B", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_CLASS_A") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_CLASS_B_ID") })
    public List<ClassB> getClassBList() {
        if (classBList == null) {
            classBList = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
        }
        return this.classBList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added @OnDelete annotation to the relationship owner side?

Comment: I added annotations only at one side:

Comment: what I am aiming for in 'cascade' is when a ClassA element is deleted, do not delete elements in classB only delete the relation between them ( remove entries from the join table ).

Comment: Do you have `@ManyToMany(targetEntity = ClassA.class)` in `B`?

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but using Hibernate, removing all the relations between a1 and Bs when deleting a1 simply consists in calling a1.getClassBList().clear(), or a1.setClassBList(Collections.emptyList());